# Telerik RadCombobox SelectedIndexedChange Event

Tags: telerik

I have a `telerik:RadCombobox` in which user can type something to filter the recoreds.

If user type some word and tabout from taht control or clicked anywhere else on the form, basically onblur , its selectedindexedchanged event is fired that I don't want.

Please advise.

I have following html code on my page:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RCBGlobalSearch" runat="server" Height="190px" Width="330px"
                                            EnableLoadOnDemand="true" ShowMoreResultsBox="true" EnableVirtualScrolling="true"
                                            OnClientDropDownClosed="OnClientDropDownClosed" MarkFirstMatch="false" Filter="None"
                                            HighlightTemplatedItems="true" Style="z-index: 9000" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RCBGlobalSearch_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                            AutoPostBack="true" ToolTip="Enter or Select Issuer or User for Search">
                                            <ExpandAnimation Type="none" />
                                            <CollapseAnimation Type="none" />
                                            <WebServiceSettings Path="~\GlobalSearchWebService.asmx" Method="GetGlobalSearchResult" />
                                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-onclienttextchange.html
- set_cancel lets you prevent the combobox from doing a postback (if AutoPostBack property is True), but doesn't let you prevent the text from changing.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function OnClientTextChange(sender, eventArgs) {
        eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
    }
</script>

<telerik:RadComboBox onclienttextchange="OnClientTextChange"....
```